# IntelliJ cucumber-jvm plugin doesn't run tests

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Running a .feature file gives me the following error:

```
  " >....< cucumber.cli.Main --format org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvmSMFormatter --monochrome --glue C:/projects/selenium-parent/selenium/src/test/resources/InformationPage.feature
Testing started at 09:20 ...


    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.feature(Unknown Source)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:108)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:94)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:82)
        at cucumber.cli.Main.run(Main.java:20)
        at cucumber.cli.Main.main(Main.java:12)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions$1.invoke(RuntimeOptions.java:94)
        ... 11 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: gherkin.formatter.model.Feature.getLine()Ljava/lang/Integer;
        at org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvmSMFormatter.feature(CucumberJvmSMFormatter.java:89)
        ... 16 more

    Process finished with exit code 1
    Empty test suite.
```

The feature file works if I invoke it via a JUnit test. So what why is it reporting **Empty test suite?**

```
Feature: Information Page

Scenario: Has expected components
    Given I navigate to the information page
    Then I should see the table component
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was due to me not having the latest cucumber-jvm plugin installed.

Comment: I am using cucumber for java plugin version 133.70 and still encounter this error. I don´t see any specific plugin for cucumber-jvm though my pom.xml is using cucumber-core 1.0.0

Comment: I had to install "Cucumber for Java".
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7212-cucumber-for-java

Answer (score 1):

I had

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm3SMFormatter
```

I needed this in the pom

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

and needed **cucumber for java** plugin installed